# How to handle Selenium timeout effectively?

Tags: selenium

```
Selenium.WaitForPageLoad("50000"); 
Selenium.Click("title");
```

Most times when it takes more than 50000, I get Timeout error. I do not want to increase the time. Is there a way to give it something like "take as long as you want"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend it, but if you want selenium to wait indefinitely, use a try-catch block and a loop:

```
while (true)
{
   try
   {
       Selenium.WaitForPageLoad("5000");
       break; //executed if page finished loading
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
       //ignore the timeout exception
   }
}
```

Again this is probably a bad idea, timeouts are generally a good thing. Depending on what you are trying to do you might want to consider checking if a particular element has finished loading as opposed to the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want it to take as long as it takes? It could hang all day...

I generally found if it takes ages to run, it had already failed a long time before.

I have used WatiN before and you can use a .WaitUntil() command to check that a specific element on the page has been loaded. Not sure what the equivalent in Selenium would be.

This link may help, if you're happy creating add-ins:

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Wait.html

Comment: waitForTextPresent, waitForElementPresent, waitForVisible ... it depends on what you're waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reverse the order of these commands?

```
Selenium.Click("title");
Selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("50000");
```

Or simply use:

```
Selenium.ClickAndWait("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
   /**
    * Put the Thread to Sleep for the specific time
    * @param delay
    */
   private void sleep(long time) {
      try {
         Thread.sleep(time);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
   }

   //Inside my Test Method

   //check if the element is loaded
   while (!webElement.isLoaded) {
        //sleep for a sec
         sleep(1000);
      }
```